# Any way to deploy extra components on top of a sfdx force:source:push?

Tags: salesforcedx, jenkins, jenkinsfile

I'm deploying code to multiple orgs in **parallel** using a separately named `project-scratch-def.json` for each one. But I've come across a case where I can only deploy some triggers to one of those orgs because the triggers depend on a feature enabled in just one of the `project-scratch-def.json` files.

Ideally, for that one case, I'd like to be able to point to a separate `sfdx-project.json` in the `sfdx force:source:push` command where that file includes a second `packageDirectories` entry pointing to the triggers. Is that possible?

(An ugly way to achieve this is to use a `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -z zipFile` command to layer MDAPI format content on top.)

<strike>Or could the triggers and their own `sfdx-project.json` just be located in separate folder in the project that the automation changes directory into and then does the `sfdx force:source:push`? Not much luck trying that so far...</strike>

Comment: force:source:deploy can replace the need for force:mdapi:deploy; it's still DX format and doesn't require any zipping. Would that help?

Comment: @sfdcfox Didn't notice that command - think it will. Will try now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks sfdcfox!

This command allows extra files to be deployed on top of a `sfdx force:source:push` with the files located in an arbitrary folder:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath config-components/config2 --json --targetusername ${org.username}
```

So I've added a `config-components` directory to the project to hold configuration specific components:

```
config
    project-scratch-def.config1.json
    project-scratch-def.config2.json
    project-scratch-def.config3.json
config-components
    config2
        force-app
            main
                ...
force-app
    main
        ...
sfdx-project.json
```

and the automation I'm using does the `sfdx force:source:deploy` only for the appropriate configuration. Note that only deployable components can be in the `--sourcepath` folder tree.